# GenericController for Asp.net Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I hate to violate DRY rule.

For url: /student/charles  /Views/Student/Show.cshtml will be rendered with Student Model.

How can I achieve it with asp.net mvc?

(I can get related model from URL)

I think I've solved. I'm catching all requests by this code:

```
  routes.MapRoute("CatchAll", "{*url}",
            new { controller = "Base", action = "Dispatch" }
        );
```

Now I'm trying to call CustomView in dispatcher.

Voila:

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Dispatch(string url)
    {
        object model = null;
        .....
        return View("~/Views/Student/Show.cshtml", model);

    }
}
```

Seems dirty but works:) I'm open any better implemantation.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Can you explain a bit more, post relevant code, give any appropriate error messages, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

I will admit that I am not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish. I first don't understand how you would violate DRY if you implemented this in the normal MVC fashion.

You would do something like this.

Model: Student.cs

```
public class Student {
  public string StudentId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller: StudentController.cs

```
public class StudentController : Controller {

  public ActionResult Student(string id) {
    // TODO: Get the student by ID and return the view displaying the student.
    return View(student);
  }
}
```

View: Student.cshtml - Make a strongly-typed view to the Student model (or a view model).

Pretty simple and very straightforward. You don't need to mess with the routing (which I wouldn't advise against that catch all - I'm not even sure what that buys you). Of course, you would need to mess with routing a little bit if you want to get URL/Student/StudentName, but that is also straightforward.

Again, I'm just spelling out basic MVC setup. I'm not sure what you're trying to keep DRY - I'm not seeing any place where you're repeating code. Perhaps you could clarify?

Comment: But If you have 10-15 classes like Student, All of them have same actions like Show,Edit,Delete,List,Index... And If you have generic dataAccess layer?

Comment: @ozz - When you say you have 10-15 classes "like" Student...that can mean a lot of things. Do you mean you have other classes that need CRUD work but are their own thing? (Course, Professor, etc.) If that's the case, they're not alike at all and should be separated. Or, do you mean you have "ForeignExchangeStudent", "FreshmanStudent", etc.? If that's the case, you may want to think about how you're modeling your data and look into abstraction at the model level - not at the Controller level.

Comment: Course,Professor,Classroom,School,Teacher...If you have generic Data Access Layer for all of them you will think like me.

Comment: @ozz - No...I would still separate them. Doing what you're doing is non-standard and is creating more problems than it is solving. DRY is important to remember, but in your particular case, I don't think it's even an issue/worry as each model object is a different thing. The views/controllers may look similar, but they are not the same.